# How to Modify Xcode Descriptive popup messages to contain Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: xcode, macos

When I linger by mouse pointer over control buttons on Xcode a Descriptive popup with a message that will show telling what will happen when I interact with that control as show in the below screenshot

How can I modify that message and add it's keyboard control shortcuts to trigger its action?

example
**Stop the running scheme or application '⌘.'**

[image]

Comment: That's not possible because those text messages are localized and programmed. You could instead create a feature request in Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: Thanks for answer 
I have added a feature request report for Apple 
https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=36273875